# In Go, when will a variable become unreachable?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Go 1.7 beta 1 was released this morning, here is [the release notes draft of Go 1.7](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.7). A new function `KeepAlive` was added to the package `runtime`. [The doc of `runtime.KeepAlive`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/#KeepAlive) has given an example:

```
type File struct { d int }
d, err := syscall.Open("/file/path", syscall.O_RDONLY, 0)
// ... do something if err != nil ...
p := &FILE{d}
runtime.SetFinalizer(p, func(p *File) { syscall.Close(p.d) })
var buf [10]byte
n, err := syscall.Read(p.d, buf[:])
// Ensure p is not finalized until Read returns.
runtime.KeepAlive(p)
// No more uses of p after this point.
```

[The doc of `runtime.SetFinalizer`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) has also given an explanation about `runtime.KeepAlive`:

> For example, if p points to a struct that contains a file descriptor
>   d, and p has a finalizer that closes that file descriptor, and if the
>   last use of p in a function is a call to syscall.Write(p.d, buf,
>   size), then p may be unreachable as soon as the program enters
>   syscall.Write. The finalizer may run at that moment, closing p.d,
>   causing syscall.Write to fail because it is writing to a closed file
>   descriptor (or, worse, to an entirely different file descriptor opened
>   by a different goroutine). To avoid this problem, call
>   runtime.KeepAlive(p) after the call to syscall.Write.

What confused me is that the variable `p` has not left its life scope yet, why will it be unreachable? Does that mean that a variable will be unreachable if only there is no use of it in the following code, no matter whether it is in its life scope?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A variable becomes unreachable when the runtime detects that the *Go* code cannot reach a point where that variable is referenced again.

In the example you posted, a [`syscall.Open()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Open) is used to open a file. The returned file descriptor (which is just an `int` value) is "wrapped" in a `struct`. Then a finalizer is attached to this struct value that closes the file descriptor. Now when this struct value becomes unreachable, its finalizer may be run at any moment, and the closing / invalidation / re-using of the file descriptor could cause unexpected behavior or errors in the execution of the `Read()` syscall.

The last use of this struct value `p` in *Go* code is when `syscall.Read()` is invoked (and the file descriptor `p.d` is passed to it). The implementation of the syscall will use that file descriptor after the *initiation* of `syscall.Read()`, it may do so up until `syscall.Read()` returns. But this use of the file descriptor is "independent" of the Go code.

So the struct value `p` is not used during the execution of the syscall, and the syscall blocks the Go code until it returns. Which means the Go runtime is allowed to mark `p` as unreachable during the execution of `Read()` (before `Read()` returns), or *even before its actual execution begins* (because `p` is only used to provide the arguments to call `Read()`.

Hence the call to [`runtime.KeepAlive()`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/#KeepAlive): since this call is *after* the `syscall.Read()` and it *references* the variable `p`, the Go runtime is not allowed to mark `p` unreachable before `Read()` returns, because this is after the `Read()` call.

Note that you could use other constructs to "keep `p` alive", e.g. `_ = p` or returning it. `runtime.KeepAlive()` does nothing magical in the background, its implementation is:

```
func KeepAlive(interface{}) {}
```

`runtime.KeepAlive()` does provide a much better alternative because:

- It clearly documents we want to keep `p` alive (to prevent runs of [Finalizers](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer)).
- Using other constructs such as `_ = p` might get "optimized" out by future compilers, but not `runtime.KeepAlive()` calls.